# How to get the image from output of Sound[]

Tags: graphics, sound

`Sound[]` generates a visual representation of notes. I would like to extract that image, only notes, without controls and borders. How can I do it?

Take this example

```
Sound[SoundNote @@@ Transpose @ {
  {"E5", "D5", "F#4", "G#4", "C#5", "B4", "D4", "E4", "B4", "A4", "C#4", "E4", "A4"},
  {1/8,  1/8,  1/4,   1/4,   1/8,   1/8,  1/4,  1/4,  1/8,  1/8,  1/4,   1/4,  1/2 }
}]
```

[image]

So far, I found that I can `Rasterize` the whole output.
Also, if I press `Ctrl Shift E` on the output it seems like there is something, but the code is not simple and very low level. I'm not sure how to translate that into graphics primitives. This method requires manual intervention anyway, and I would like to get the image automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FirstCase[ToBoxes[sound], g_GraphicsBox :> 
  First @ Cases[ToExpression[g], Inset[display_, ___] :> display, All]
]
```

Also if you dig through the definition, the relevant part is:

```
{samples, midi} = Sound`NormalizeSound[sound];
sampleRate = Sound`SoundSampleRate[samples];
Sound`SequencePlot[midi, sampleRate]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `ToBoxes` then extract the part corresponding to the `GraphicsBox` with the purple note `RectangleBox` boxes. This happens to be part `[[1,1,2,1,1]]` which you can get with a bit of experimentation. Then remove the frame if you don't want that by using a replacement with `Nothing`. Finally, use `ToExpression` to convert the result into something visible - which should have a `Graphics` head:

```
s = Sound[
     SoundNote @@@ 
      Transpose@{{"E5", "D5", "F#4", "G#4", "C#5", "B4", "D4", "E4", 
         "B4", "A4", "C#4", "E4", "A4"}, {1/8, 1/8, 1/4, 1/4, 1/8, 
         1/8, 1/4, 1/4, 1/8, 1/8, 1/4, 1/4, 1/2}}]

ToExpression[
 ToBoxes[s][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]] /. {Rule[Frame, True] :> Nothing, 
   Rule[FrameStyle, _] :> Nothing}
 ]
```

[image: notes]